# Rails: Blocking an user using routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I have a special url which I would want only few people to have access to. I have a list of super users stored as an array in the app.yml. How can I use this array in :requirements section of a specific route in the routes.rb file to allow only those super users access to this route? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. `:requirements` are related to route parameters only.

Which is, in my opinion, a good thing. It's a well known convention to have authentication logic in controllers.

Answer (score 3):

Like Pedro said.. authentication logic should be in controller code.
Take a look at before_filters, where you specify methods that will be called before (all or specified) actions in a controller are run. You can use such a method to deny actions from running. Look for the section named Filter Chain Halting [here](http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)

[:requirements](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html) is for specifying constraints for parts of the URL for the route to match. Usually regular expressions are specified as shown here.

```
map.geocode 'geocode/:postalcode', :controller => 'geocode',
              :action => 'show', :requirements => { :postalcode => /\d{5}(-\d{4})?/ }
```